# Why does unusable password have random string, in Django's User authentication?

Tags: python, django

When I read `django.contrib.auth` code, I found this code in `django.contrib.auth.hassers.make_password`.

```
UNUSABLE_PASSWORD_PREFIX + get_random_string(UNUSABLE_PASSWORD_SUFFIX_LENGTH)
```

However, I don't understand why unusable password is not only `UNUSABLE_PASSWORD_PREFIX`, which is **'!'**.

There is this code, in `django.contrib.auth.hassers.is_password_usable`.

```
if encoded is None or encoded.startswith(UNUSABLE_PASSWORD_PREFIX):
    return False
```

I think random string is meaningless.

Comment: It eliminates the chance of brute-forcing a password reset token when the `SECRET_KEY` is known by an attacker. See [#20079](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/20079).

Comment: Extra 'paranoia', perhaps. Also, it probably meets other password complexity requirements.

Comment: That is, making it an unknown random password doesn't 'hurt' anything, even if somehow an attacker was able to sneak in `UNUSABLE_PASSWORD_PREFIX = "haha"` on the check; a code-level attack on the generation would already have thwarted the security. Also the "!" was chosen as it will never match a hex-emitting hash function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The password hash is used to generate a password reset token. By reducing the complexity, it opens up the reset token to a brute-force attack. The attacker has to have the `SECRET_KEY` for this to work.

To generate the password reset token, the ID of the user, the date in `last_login`, the password hash and the `SECRET_KEY` are used[1]. For superusers, it is reasonably likely that the ID is `1` and the `last_login` date is within a few weeks of when the site came live, i.e. the superuser has never logged in and it's the creation date of the account.

If the `SECRET_KEY` is known, the ID is pretty much guessable and the password hash is known, an attacker only has to guess the datetime, which is within a few weeks timespan. A resolution of a second is used (the microsecond part of the `last_login` is set to 0), which leaves around 600K possible values per week. With time and patience, this value can be brute-forced and the attacker can set a new, usable password for the superuser or admin account.

There are quite a few "if"s in this attack, but it is a possible attack vector. The random hash in the unusable password increases the entropy of the password reset token for unusable passwords, and eliminates this kind of attack.

[1] https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/tokens.py#L66

Comment: *Why* would the password hash be used to generate the *nonce* reset token? Please provide supporting code/links, even though the description is pretty clear. (And if it is as described, then shame on the code authors for making the reset based on an existing password.)

Comment: @user2864740 Please open a ticket and/or submit a pull request.

Comment: I'd  like to stress that this issue has long been eliminated. The OP is asking about the exact code that completely eliminated this issue. I only explain what the possible attack vector would be if the code in the question wasn't  used.

Answer (score 1):

The unusable password is used to generate a reset token for password reset.

Therefore knowing it's value `!` is less secure than a random string.

Source: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/20079

Comment: How is it "less secure" if the user *cannot use it to logon*?

Comment: Because a possible attacker who knows the `SECRET_KEY` can brute-force the reset token, and set any password they'd like to log in themselves. It's an attack vector which possibly gives an attacker admin or superuser rights, so yeah, it's less secure.

Comment: @knbk *How* can the attacker do that again? The reset token is different from the set-non-usable-password. The ticket reads: "An attacker who knows SECRET_KEY has a practical chance of success *if there are admin users with no password set.*"

Comment: Anyway, choosing "!" for the prefix was also done because *there is no hex-emitting hash function that can generate this value*. Note that it was the *encoded* (aka hashes) value that was set. Please justify this answer, as I don't think the link relates - there *is* a password set; but one that will *never* pass a hash check, much less the initial guard.

Comment: The password is not the attack vector, the password reset token is. With this, an attacker can set a new, usable password. The random hash increases entropy beyond what can be brute-forced.

Comment: @knbk Then some coders need a kick in the face and a redirect to Wikipedia's nonce article.